# How to jump to specific page using Query Cursor?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing my website in python(webapp2) and google data store in back end.
I have added query cursor for pagination and it's working good but it has only next and previous functions for pagination, the question is that how i will jump to specific page like i am on page 1 and i want to jump to page 3, how i will manage it in Query Cursor?

i have also visited below links but didn't find any solution
https://www.the-swamp.info/blog/pagination-google-app-engine/

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/query-cursors

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Datastore doesn't know the number of results found by your query.

You can however use some tricks to simulate a full pagination.
For example one technique is to generate a certain number of cursors in a loop and generating the "last page" one.

Like in the following pseudo-code:

```
(results, next_curs, more) = model.query....fetch_page(...)

for p in xrange(5):
    # generate cursor for page number 'b' 
    # by using the next_cursor from previous page
    (results, next_curs, more) = model.....fetch_page(cursor=next_cursor,...)
```

As you don't access the results cursor the performance is somewhat acceptable (depending on your models complexity, query complexity and such).
You can tweak it on your data.